# I'm trying to create a "top users by cumulative sum" dataframe in R

Tags: r

First question! I'm going to try to be as specific as possible, but please bear with me.

I have a dataframe in R that holds speedrun data. There are two columns that I'm interested in: **player** and **record_duration**.

My goal is to create a 'leaderboard' of sorts, where I rank the players by the cumulative sum of their record durations (total # of days they held a record for).

My first thought was to create a new dataframe, which I called **new_df**. It included only distinct player names, as well as a "cum. sum." column, which I initialized as 0's.

```
original_df <- data.frame(
  player = c('alex', 'rob', 'rob', 'alex', 'dan', 'alex'),
  record_duration = c(10, 15, 12, 44, 2, 12))

new_df <- data.frame(
  player = c('alex', 'rob', 'dan'),
  cumsum = 0)

original_df: 
  player record_duration
1   alex              10
2    rob              15
3    rob              12
4   alex              44
5    dan               2
6   alex              12

new_df: 
    player cumsum
1   alex      0
2    rob      0
3    dan      0
```

My idea was to

1. Loop through **original_df**, searching for the *i*'th player's name in **new_df**
2. Add the corresponding **record_duration** value to **cum_sum** in that player's row.

Unfortunately, I've hit a wall! I can't seem to figure out how to write that loop, and I have a feeling that this kind of situation doesn't even really need a loop. This *feels* like a simple enough problem, but I'm floundering! I'd appreciate any advice.

```
DESIRED OUTPUT:
  player cumsum
1   alex      66
2    rob      27
3    dan      2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate but here it is:

```
new_df <- aggregate(record_duration ~ player, original_df, sum)
new_df <- new_df[order(-new_df$record_duration), ]
new_df
#  player record_duration
#1   alex              66
#3    rob              27
#2    dan               2
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a ton, Rui. I was unfamiliar with the aggregate function, but it worked like a charm.